# Maven - why is jar file generated along with war file?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

The following shows part of a pom.xml that I have. When I ran "mvn package" or "mvn war", the war is generated along with a jar file named "mlm-classes.jar".

Why is the JAR file generated? I mean, it's not specified in the pom.xml that I want the JAR file.

If I want a different JAR file name, how do I specify?

```
...
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>mlm</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/j*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>web/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>urlrewrite.xml</include>
                            <include>weblogic.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` means that you want to generate an additional JAR with the classes.

BTW: `mvn war` is not a valid Maven command.

Comment: Thanks. That explains the mystery. Also, I had meant "mvn war:war".

Comment: What if I also want a jar file with only the classes, and a different name, say "mlm.jar"?

Comment: Then you should put the classes into a separate project or module and use a dependency in your war project. Furthermore, please never use `mvn war:war`. It does not produce sensible output.